# In GAP, how can I create a group isomorphic but not equal to a given group?

Tags: group-theory, math-software, gap

Sorry if the question title is confusing. Let me try to explain my question over an example. Please consider

```
gap> G := SmallGroup(24, 12);;
```

Without knowing that $G$ is $S_4$, can we define a new group which is $S_4$ but not equal to $G$. For example,

```
gap> H := SmallGroup(24, 12);;
gap> G = H;
false
gap> K := ShallowCopy(Group(GeneratorsOfGroup(G)));;
gap> K = G;
true
```

So I am trying to find a way to create a new group which has the same structure with $G$ without using `SmallGroup`. I used `ShallowCopy` to do that but I failed.

I want to do this, because if $S\leq G$, I cannot use the function `IsConjugatorIsomorphism` to see that whether a map is given by an element in S yet not in G. Since `Parent(S)` is $G$, it does not work. We can also use `ConjugatorOfConjugatorIsomorphism` to check that, but I would like to avoid doing this as I suspect there might be a simpler solution.

Edit.
Another attempt that not helps me is below:

```
gap> S4 := SmallGroup(24, 12);;
gap> D8 := AllSubgroups(S4)[26];;
gap> StructureDescription(D8);
"D8"
gap> D8PermRep := Image(SmallerDegreePermutationRepresentation(
>                         Image(IsomorphismPermGroup(D8))));;
gap> center := Center(D8PermRep);
Group([ (1,3)(2,4) ])
gap> ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(D8PermRep);
[ Group( () )^G, Group( [ (2,4) ] )^G, Group( [ (1,3)(2,4) ] )^G,
  Group( [ (1,2)(3,4) ] )^G, Group( [ (1,3), (2,4) ] )^G, 
  Group( [ (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4) ] )^G, 
  Group( [ (1,4,3,2), (1,3)(2,4) ] )^G, 
  Group( [ (1,3), (2,4), (1,2)(3,4) ] )^G ]
gap> C2 := ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(D8PermRep)[4][1];
Group([ (1,2)(3,4) ])
gap> IsConjugatorIsomorphism(AllIsomorphisms(center, C2)[1]);
true
gap> Parent(C2) = S4;
false
```

Comment: You say you want to detect "whether a map is given by an element in $S$ yet not in $G$". Do you mean the other way around? If so, you could restrict your morphism $G \to G$ to a morphism $S \to S$ and then call `IsInnerAutomorphism` on it.

Comment: What I meant is if $P \leq S$, the map $P \rightarrow S$  can be returned true by ```IsConjugatorIsomorphism``` even if it is not given by an element in $S$ since ```Parent(S)``` is $G$.

Comment: I wonder if what you are asking is really what you need? Note that "conjugator isomorphism" is a special type of isomorphism, and there is no guarantee that any given isomorphism has that type, even if *could* have that type...   Anyway: I wonder if what you really want to do is to test if two subgroups are conjugate or not? Put another way: what do you *really* want to compute?

Comment: @Max Of course, the problem of checking a map is a conjugator isomorhism or not can be solved in many different ways. For example, If $A, B \leq H \leq G$, and I want the elements of $H$ that conjugate $A$ to $B$, I can simply check that `A^h <> B` where $h$ runovers the set `AsList(RightTransversal(H, Center(H)))`, then I can compare the elements by using `ConjugatorIsomorphism` with the map that I am given to check whether it is conjugator isomorphism or not. However using the `IsConjugatorIsomorphism` is not helpful as I explained, and I complain about this actually.

Comment: @Max But my question is different, because, I discovered that I cannot copy a group or get rid of its parent, so I asked for a way to do that.

Comment: Derek's answer already indicated how to make a fresh copy of a group: using the `Group` command on a set of generators, `Group(GeneratorsOfGroup(G))` does this generally. But what you say about "checking [if] a map is a conjugator isomorphism" makes no sense to me; a conjugator isomorphism in the GAP sense only exists between groups which have a common parent. Otherwise, the concept is not well-defined. So for an arbitrary isomorphism, this cannot possibly be checked. Hence my question if maybe you really wanted to ask something different all along?

Comment: @Max But I want this copy not to be equal to my group, I think I clearly indicated that. That's why I tried to use `ShallowCopy` (using it's funny and stupid actually). In Derek's answer, as you can see, `G1 = G1` returns true.

Comment: In GAP, permutation groups are always equal if they have the same content. If you really want to have to non-equal copies, you'll have to either use different types of groups (e.g. fp-groups) or have one "copy" operate on the set [1..5]  and the other on e.g. [6..10]. However, I can't think of any computation that would *need* such a thing.

Comment: So you could e.g. use `IsomorphismFpGroup` on your group to get an isomorphic but non-equal copy, even if the input is a perm group; the output will be an isomorphism to an Fp group.

Comment: @Max Your suggestion works perfectly! I suggest that you can make this answer. Besides, GAP checks whether any group homomorphism is a conjugator isomorphism or not. I do not understand why you are giving an argument on this.

Comment: Yes GAP allows you to test the property `IsConjugatorIsomorphism` for any homomorphism -- but the answer will always be "false" for any homomorphism for which source and range differ.\

Comment: (To clarify, in my last comment I should have said "for which source and range don't have a common parent")

Comment: So that's why returning false is useful rather than giving an error. I do not understand what makes you think that I am using the `IsConjugatorIsomorphism`between the subgroups who do not enjoy having the same parent? Am I missing something here? Have you understood that why I've given that specific example?

Comment: `Parent(C2) = S4;` returns false since this is what has been asked. `Parent(C2)` is isomorphic to `D8`.

Comment: @Alex Event if `Parent(C2)` is `D8`, GAP behaves like the parent is still `S4`, because you cannot conjugate the center of `D8` to another subgroup.

Comment: Hmm... May happen that instead of using built-in `IsConjugatorIsomorphism` you need to write own code to check the condition you need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IsomorphismFpGroup(G)` for this purpose.

But note that `IsConjugatorIsomorphism` will always return `false` for such an isomorphism if `G` is not an fp group (for an fp group, it will return the identity map, which trivially is a conjugator isomorphism)

Comment: SmallGroup library never returns a group in Fp format, right?

Comment: SmallGroup only returns perm groups and pc groups.

Comment: Good, otherwise that method would fail to copy subgroups.

Comment: That method does *not* copy anything. It produce a new, independent group, which happens to be isomorphic to the input group

Comment: +1 for persistence in getting OP to divulge what the underlying goal was!

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure that this is what happened here... or maybe we did figure out their immediate goal, but I still have a nagging suspicion that it is the completely wrong approach for their *actual* problem...

Answer (score 7):

Equality of groups can be difficult to define usefully, and GAP's answer can be hard to predict.

```
gap> G1 := Group([(1,2),(1,3,4)]);
Group([ (1,2), (1,3,4) ])
gap> G2 := Group([(2,3,4),(1,4)]);
Group([ (2,3,4), (1,4) ])
gap> G1 = G2;
true
```

Yes, because they are the same subgroup of $S_4$. But:

```
gap> G1 := SmallGroup(24,10);
<pc group of size 24 with 4 generators>
gap> G2 := SmallGroup(24,10);
<pc group of size 24 with 4 generators>
gap> G1 = G2;
false
```

Presumably each definition is constructing a separate object.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what the goal of creating an isomorphic (but not equal) group object is, but GAP seems to have a plethora of ways to do this.  For example:

```
gap> G := SmallGroup(24,12);;
gap> Size(G);
24
gap> H := Group( (1,2,3,4), (1,2) );;
gap> Size(H);
24
gap> G = H;
false
gap> Iso := IsomorphismPermGroup(G);;
gap> K := Image(Iso);;
gap> Size(K);
24
gap> K = G;
false
gap> K = H;
false
```

Here we began with your way of constructing `G` as $S_4$, followed by constructing `H` as the familiar permutation group.  Both are groups of order $24$, and GAP does not consider them to be equal.

We can further create the action-isomorphism object `Iso` and define the permutation group `K` which is the image of that mapping from `G`. Again we have a group of order $24$ which GAP does not consider to be equal to `G` nor equal to `H`.

Section [43.3](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap43.html#X7E468B64860D5604) of the GAP reference manual may suggest to you something even closer to your intended purpose.

Comment: This solution you suggest seems partially works for me. I should not be able to map the center of a group to a different subgroup by conjugation, however, GAP still does not work properly at this stage. I edited my question, and explained why your suggestion not works for me.

Comment: I'm still not clear what you are trying to check with GAP.  The body of the Question asked about "whether a map is given by an element in $S$ yet not in $G$", and the Comment above suggests an application with $S$ the center of $G$.  Are you given an element in $S$?  Are you trying to test whether an element is in the center of $G$?

Comment: I just want to use  the ```IsConjugatorIsomorphism``` function over the subgroups, however, that function always checks the elements of the Ambient group, for this reason, I tried to copy this group to get rid from the Ambient group. Even with your method, it does not work. If you consider my example, there should not be a conjugator isomorphism that moves the center of the group. So I am looking for an efficient way to handle this issue over the much larger groups. Besides, I am getting so curious if I cannot figure out what is happening.

Comment: It seems to me you didn't use enough words in the body of your Question to setup this problem.  Instead of just having one subgroup of another group, $S\leq G$, you actually have a third group $P\leq S\leq G$.  The difficulty arises because the function `IsConjugatorIsomorphism` treats not only $G$ as the "parent" of $S$, but $G$ is the ambient group for $P$ also.  Am I getting warmer?

Comment: Of course, you need to consider the subgroups of $S$, which is one of the reasons why we use ```IsConjugatorIsomorphism```.  In my question, I explained why I want to copy the subgroup. I thought it does not work because it has a Parent group. And, thanks to you, after copying the group I learned that there is a ghost Parent group, even if GAP says there is not, which is another problem now.

Comment: I did not have much thoughts about this so far, but if `Iso:=IsomorphismPermGroup(G)` and `K:=Image(Iso)` then you can use `Iso` to find in `K` the images of elements of `G` and subgroups of `G` under this mapping. Would this help?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: I'm not sure what the underlying goal of the Original Poster was.  The title asks about getting `K` not equal to `G` (but isomorphic to it as GAP judges things), so that part works.  Perhaps your idea (using subgroups of `K`) could be helpful to Cadenza, but it seems to be in his/her hands.

Comment: Dear @Alex, please see the code on my question to see why this is not the exact solution.

Comment: @Cadenza but I don't see the use of `IsomorphismPermGroup` in the code from your question - what do I miss?

Comment: @Alex It is there :) `D8PermRep := Image(SmallerDegreePermutationRepresentation(Image(IsomorphismPermGroup(D8))));;` The line is just too long.

Comment: At the risk of making the Comments "too long", having code using `ConjugatorOfConjugatorIsomorphism` successfully do what you want (albeit with some overhead) would shed light on what the goal is (beyond what the title suggests).

Comment: @Cadenza ah, right. I've edited it to make more readable. Hope new answer by Max helps now.

Comment: @Alex Yes, it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have laughed a lot when I realized that how super simple the solution actually is. Here is how we do it:

```
gap> G1 := SmallGroup(24,12);
<pc group of size 24 with 4 generators>
gap> G2 := SmallGroup(IdGroup(G1));
<pc group of size 24 with 4 generators>
gap> G1 = G2;
false
```

But if `G1` does not belong to `SmallGroup` library, I guess Max's solution might be more useful.

Comment: This only works for solvable groups; for non-solvable groups, a permutation group is returned, and then the comparison will give "true"

Answer (score 0):

As for the examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4341671/1056952) given by [Derek Holt](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2820/derek-holt), the equality between the two groups can be checked as follows:

```
gap> G1 := SmallGroup(24,10);
<pc group of size 24 with 4 generators>
gap> G2 := SmallGroup(24,10);
<pc group of size 24 with 4 generators>
gap> G1 = G2;
false
gap> AsSet(List(G1,x ->String(x)))=AsSet(List(G2,x ->String(x)));
true
gap> Image(IsomorphismPermGroup(G1))=Image(IsomorphismPermGroup(G2));
true
```